# Simple barcode scanner using Python/Kivy for android devices

Tags: android, python, kivy

First off - I am not a mobile developer, I started programming this summer with python and javascript. I only wish to create a simple application that would allow for:

- scanning a whole bunch of things.
- exporting a list/array of scanned barcodes as string elements somehow so i can process the data in my Python script (it shows what is missing from the shelf comparing it to database, wrote it in like 1 day).

Is it possible using Kivy? I'm dwelling for many hours trying various example codes but nothing seems to work, furthest i got was taking a picture using kivy written app, but it required 5 confirmation steps...
If it is impossible in Kivy, I would be very thankful for estimation of minimal time and work required in some other framework, keeping in mind that I don't know any Java, only Javascript and Python.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is completely possible .It is already done [here](https://github.com/tito/android-zbar-qrcode).This example is made by tito ,founding member of Kivy.In the example external library zbar is used for scanning.

Comment: did you tried to compile & run it? I cannot manage to run it properly (I get an error regarding iconv library - posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989473/kivy-jnius-no-iconv-in-java-library-path)